# select all events within the next hour

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database, there is a table, where I store daily recurring events.

I store the time of the event in the field `time`, that has the 'TIME' type. How do I select all events within the next hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
TIMEDIFF(event.time, TIME(NOW())) < TIME('01:00:00')
```

See [MySQL date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE TIMEDIFF(`time`,TIME(NOW())) < TIME('01:00:00');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This query seems not to work properly. for the current time (which is 12:36 for me right now), it returns values from 01:10:00 to 13:37:00. (see http://www.fishnation.de/bachelor/code/caching/wvv/wvv-select.php ). Is it because of the 24h-format I'm using?

Comment: it should work in 24h format. try to encapsulate your `time` field with backticks(`\``), like i did in my query. I'm not really sure, but I think `time` is a keyword in mysql, therefor it must be marked as column by surrounding it with the backticks

Comment: as Sjoerd wrote, it has to be `< TIME('01:00:00')` to work... thanks for your efforts, though!